# Adding imxvpudec in google coral

Tags: gstreamer-1.0, google-coral, imx8

I'm In the process of adding v4l2h264dec or imxvpudec

v4l2h264dec was not able to add. so i tried imxvpudec using the repo https://github.com/Freescale/gstreamer-imx

but the dependencies  libimxdmabuffer  not installing which is saying

--imx-linux-headers-path is not set

if i set the path then its giving

Could not find linux/mxcfb.h in path

how to resolve this ?

is this procedure for running os or cross compilation?

and what are these path ?

```
CC
CFLAGS
LDFLAGS
PKG_CONFIG_PATH
PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
```

please give me the detailed information

thank you

Comment: Have you managed to solve it?